# How can I get the selectnav on my mobile site to load instantly when screen is loaded?

Tags: jquery, html, blogger

On the mobile version of my blog, the selectnav takes a few seconds to load. I would like it to load instantly so it doesn't suddenly appear.

The jquery for the selectnav plugin is below:

```
// Plugin: SelectNav.js ~ url: https://github.com/lukaszfiszer/selectnav.js
window.selectnav=function(){"use strict";var e=function(e,t){function c(e){var t;if(!e)e=window.event;if(e.target)t=e.target;else if(e.srcElement)t=e.srcElement;if(t.nodeType===3)t=t.parentNode;if(t.value)window.location.href=t.value}function h(e){var t=e.nodeName.toLowerCase();return t==="ul"||t==="ol"}function p(e){for(var t=1;document.getElementById("selectnav"+t);t++);return e?"selectnav"+t:"selectnav"+(t-1)}function d(e){a++;var t=e.children.length,n="",l="",c=a-1;if(!t){return}if(c){while(c--){l+=o}l+=" "}for(var v=0;v<t;v++){var m=e.children[v].children[0];if(typeof m!=="undefined"){var g=m.innerText||m.textContent;var y="";if(r){y=m.className.search(r)!==-1||m.parentNode.className.search(r)!==-1?f:""}if(i&&!y){y=m.href===document.URL?f:""}n+='<option value="'+m.href+'" '+y+">"+l+g+"</option>";if(s){var b=e.children[v].children[1];if(b&&h(b)){n+=d(b)}}}}if(a===1&&u){n='<option value="">'+u+"</option>"+n}if(a===1){n='<select class="selectnav" id="'+p(true)+'">'+n+"</select>"}a--;return n}e=document.getElementById(e);if(!e){return}if(!h(e)){return}if(!("insertAdjacentHTML"in window.document.documentElement)){return}document.documentElement.className+=" js";var n=t||{},r=n.activeclass||"active",i=typeof n.autoselect==="boolean"?n.autoselect:true,s=typeof n.nested==="boolean"?n.nested:true,o=n.indent||"?",u=n.label||"Menu",a=0,f=" selected ";e.insertAdjacentHTML("afterend",d(e));var l=document.getElementById(p());if(l.addEventListener){l.addEventListener("change",c)}if(l.attachEvent){l.attachEvent("onchange",c)}return l};return function(t,n){e(t,n)}}();$(document).ready(function(){selectnav('menu-main-nav');});
```

The link to my blog is: https://futuremag-demo.blogspot.com